# multithreading: sharing by communicating

Tags: c++, multithreading, message-queue

Recently, I've become aware of this dichotomy between "communicating by sharing" and "sharing by communicating". I've always written multithreaded coded by communicating by sharing: using mutexes and other synchronization mechanisms to lock shared data. I'm trying to envision what our code would look like if we did not have shared data.

We have an application in C++ in which multiple boost io_service::strands share large arrays (on the order of 1 MB) of data. I've noticed there's a boost io_service::strand::post() function. Does sharing by communicating (i.e. message passing) make sense when sharing such large data? Would it make sense to copy these large arrays between threads using post()? Should the program be structured to copy subsets of these arrays at a time instead?